# Cannot simulate user type in Input using Jest unit test. fireEvent, userEvent do not work

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, user-input, user-event

I have an input field and wish to stimulate the type-in during a unit test. Tried all the methods recommended on internet but still no luck, here is my code:

```
// In component
<div className="input-area">
                    <div className="subtitle">Put your answer here</div>
                    <Input onChange={({detail}) => onInputChange(detail.value)}
                           value={name}  data-testid="add-input"/>
                </div>
    

// In test
    test("the input field should take user's input", async () => {
        render(<testModal />);
        const inputMessage = screen.getByTestId("add-input");
        inputMessage.focus(); // take this line off has no effect
        await userEvent.keyboard("testTyping");
    
        expect(inputMessage).toHaveValue("testTyping");
    });
```

Also tried using `fireEvent.change` and `userEvent.type` but no luck. The error is `Expected the element to have value: testTyping Received: undefined` Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6):

From the doc [keyboard(text, options)](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/#keyboardtext-options):

> You should use `userEvent.keyboard` if you want to just simulate pressing buttons on the keyboard. You should use `userEvent.type` if you just want to conveniently insert some text into an input field or textarea.

Try:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

test("the input field should take user's input", async () => {
  render(<testModal />);
  await userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("add-input"), 'testTyping');
  expect(inputMessage).toHaveValue("testTyping");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test if input validation error is triggering after `onChange` but `fireEvent.change` did not do the job for me.

Thanks to answer by @lin-du I was able to trigger the error using `userEvent`.
But still don't understand how `fireEvent.change` do it, since i'm handling the error with onChange in my component.

```
  it('shows error if input is greater than 50', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<TestComponent />);
  const inputElem = getByTestId('input-test-id');
  await user.type(inputElem, '51');
  const errorText = getByText('value must be less than 50.');
  expect(errorText).toBeTruthy();
});
```